# Check if all elements in MongoDB array match a given query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

Here's how my document looks:

```
nookstore = {
     "name": "Nook store",
     "categories": ["bookstore"],
     "working_hours": [
        {"opens": 8*60*60, "closes": 21*60*60 },
        {"opens": 8*60*60, "closes": 21*60*60 },
        {"opens": 8*60*60, "closes": 21*60*60 },
        {"opens": 8*60*60, "closes": 21*60*60 },
        {"opens": 8*60*60, "closes": 21*60*60 },
        {"opens": 8*60*60, "closes": 21*60*60 },
        {"opens": 9*60*60, "closes": 20*60*60 },
     ]
  }

  ...

kindlestore = {
     "name": "Kindle store",
     "categories": ["bookstore"],
     "working_hours": [
        {"opens": 0, "closes": 24*60*60 },
        {"opens": 0, "closes": 24*60*60 },
        {"opens": 0, "closes": 24*60*60 },
        {"opens": 0, "closes": 24*60*60 },
        {"opens": 0, "closes": 24*60*60 },
        {"opens": 0, "closes": 24*60*60 },
        {"opens": 0, "closes": 24*60*60 },
     ],
  }
```

I'm looking for the 24-hours stores, i.e. the stores in which **every element** of `working_hours` opens at `0` and closes at `24*60*60` (seconds after midnight).

I tried using `$all` and `$elemMatch`, but they work in cases where I need to match if at least one of the elements of an array matches a given criteria (which I don't need).

Comment: It would be most efficient if you stored that as a distinct field when the document was saved.

Comment: Or, you'd need to check every array index for each condition with an `$and` ... which would look messy and may be a bit slow. If you used the aggregation framework, you could group and sum based on the opens/closes time and check for times when it was == 7.

Comment: I added an answer with an aggregation solution.

Answer (score 1):

While I think this would be best if you modified the schema to include the special status as another field (`open24hours`), you could use the aggregation framework to find matches.

```
db.stores.aggregate({$unwind : '$working_hours' }, 
   { $group : { 
       _id : { 
         name: '$name', 
         opens: '$working_hours.opens', 
         closes: '$working_hours.closes' }, 
      total: { $sum : 1 }
      }
  }, 
  { $match : { total : 7 } })
```

This unwinds the hours opened, then groups on the name, opens and closes times, thereby making a unique combination, and then totals the number of matches for each combination. If there were 7 for the total, then it matched on all 7 days. You could do further matches to only find `opens` at `0` and `closes` at `86400`.

Results:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "name" : "Kindle store",
                            "opens" : 0,
                            "closes" : 86400
                    },
                    "total" : 7
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the aggregation framework, probably in multiple ways. This is one that just groups to find unique open/close times and matches at the end on a single open/close time that's midnight to midnight.

```js
db.stores.aggregate(
  [ 
    { $unwind: '$working_hours' },
    { $group: { _id: '$name', times: { $addToSet: '$working_hours' } } },
    { $unwind: '$times' },
    { $group: { _id: '$_id', times: { $push: '$times' }, cnt: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $match: { 'times.opens': 0, 'times.closes': 86400, cnt: 1 } }
  ]
)
```

EDIT: Another, probably better alternative is to match as early as possible to not have to group values that aren't relevant;

```
db.stores.aggregate(
  [
    { $unwind: '$working_hours' },
    { $match: { 'working_hours.opens': 0, 'working_hours.closes': 86400 } },
    { $group: { _id: '$name', cnt: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $match: { 'cnt': 7 } }
  ]
)
```

EDIT2: It can also be done without the aggregate framework by finding all stores that don't have a non matching time;

```
db.stores.find({
  'working_hours': { 
    $not: { 
      $elemMatch: {
        $or:[ { 'opens': { $ne: 0 } }, { 'closes': { $ne: 86400 } } ]
      }
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```